# how to use different keyspaces in spring MVC when I use hectorTemplate to operate Cassandra?

Tags: spring-mvc, cassandra

At first, why I want to use different keyspaces?
Because I want to write JUnit Test, but I need another keyspace for testing.
I am using Spring MVC.
And I use the hectorTemplate autowired in spring.

```
<!--  cassandra configuration -->
    <bean id="cassandraHostConfigurator" class="me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.CassandraHostConfigurator">
        <constructor-arg value="${cassandra.url}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="cluster" class="me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.ThriftCluster">
        <constructor-arg value="${cassandra.cluster}" />
        <constructor-arg ref="cassandraHostConfigurator" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="consistencyLevelPolicy" class="me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.ConfigurableConsistencyLevel">
       <property name="defaultReadConsistencyLevel" value="${cassandra.defaultReadConsistencyLevel}"></property>
       <property name="defaultWriteConsistencyLevel" value="${cassandra.defaultWriteConsistencyLevel}"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="keyspace" class="me.prettyprint.hector.api.factory.HFactory" factory-method="createKeyspace">
        <constructor-arg value="${cassandra.keyspace}" />
        <constructor-arg ref="cluster" />
        <constructor-arg ref="consistencyLevelPolicy" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="hectorTemplate" class="me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.spring.HectorTemplateImpl">
        <property name="cluster" ref="cluster" />
        <property name="keyspace" ref="keyspace" />
        <property name="replicationStrategyClass" value="org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy" />
        <property name="replicationFactor" value="1" />
    </bean>
```

So I should do what to add another keyspace?
Thanks for the help.(n.n)!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- Keyspace1 -->

 <bean id="keyspace1" class="me.prettyprint.hector.api.factory.HFactory" factory-method="createKeyspace">
        <constructor-arg value="${cassandra.keyspace1}" />
        <constructor-arg ref="cluster" />
        <constructor-arg ref="consistencyLevelPolicy" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="hectorTemplate1" class="me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.spring.HectorTemplateImpl">
        <property name="cluster" ref="cluster" />
        <property name="keyspace" ref="keyspace1" />
        <property name="replicationStrategyClass" value="org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy" />
        <property name="replicationFactor" value="1" />
    </bean>


<!-- Keyspace2 -->

 <bean id="keyspace2" class="me.prettyprint.hector.api.factory.HFactory" factory-method="createKeyspace">
        <constructor-arg value="${cassandra.keyspace2}" />
        <constructor-arg ref="cluster" />
        <constructor-arg ref="consistencyLevelPolicy" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="hectorTemplate2" class="me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.spring.HectorTemplateImpl">
        <property name="cluster" ref="cluster" />
        <property name="keyspace" ref="keyspace2" />
        <property name="replicationStrategyClass" value="org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy" />
        <property name="replicationFactor" value="1" />
    </bean>
```

---

For JUnit test, you SHOULD use the same keyspace and use an **embedded** Cassandra. Check **[here](https://github.com/jsevellec/cassandra-unit)**.  There is no reason to create another keyspace just for testing.

Comment: but I do not know how to distingusih the two keyspace in the java code， is there any judgement？Because I need test the method in the service layer, and the DAO method cannot be altered.

Comment: In the test code for DAO, let's say MyDaoTest, you should **inject** a Hector cluster & keyspace that is bootstrapped with the Cassandra Unit.